# I want to show next best volume discount to customer for total amount

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

i have two volume discount for total amount in cart

1. If total amount is greater then 50 and less then 100
2. If total amount is greater then 101 and less then 200

see images[image: volume discount 1]

[image: volume discount 2]

For example if i have $50 total amount in cart then rule 1 will apply but i want to show a offer message that shop $61 more to get 50% discount

Any Help

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a paid promobanner extension from Aheadworks that basically does what you are looking for. To make this yourself, and make it scaleable it would take a whole lot more code than one answer post

Comment: @Sander Thanks a lot bro. :) .I will check it