# Check Magento volume discount condition manually

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, array

i want to Check Magento volume discount condition manually for show notification message to customer shop $xx more  to get Y% discount. 
see this post
[I want to show next best volume discount to customer for total amount](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64701/i-want-to-show-next-best-volume-discount-to-customer-for-total-amount)

i have all conditions is array

```
    $myarray = array(
  "type" =>  "salesrule/rule_condition_combine",
  "attribute" => NULL,
  "operator" => NULL,
  "value" =>  "1",
  "is_value_processed" => NULL,
  "aggregator" =>  "all",
  "conditions" => array(  
         "type" =>  "salesrule/rule_condition_combine",
         "attribute" => NULL,
          "operator" => NULL,
          "value" => "1",
          "is_value_processed" => NULL,
          "aggregator" =>  "all",
          "conditions" => array(
                                     array(
                                      "type" => "salesrule/rule_condition_address",
                                      "attribute" =>  "base_subtotal",
                                      "operator" =>  ">=",
                                      "value" =>  "50",
                                      "is_value_processed" =>false,
                                        ),
                                    array(
                                      "type" =>  "salesrule/rule_condition_address",
                                      "attribute" => "base_subtotal",
                                      "operator" => "<=",
                                      "value" => "100",
                                      "is_value_processed" => false,
                                    ),
                array(
                  "type" => "salesrule/rule_condition_product_found",
                  "attribute" => NULL,
                  "operator" => NULL,
                  "value" =>  "1",
                  "is_value_processed" => NULL,
                  "aggregator" =>  "all",
                  "conditions" => array(
                                        array (
                                          "type" =>  "salesrule/rule_condition_product",
                                          "attribute" =>  "category_ids",
                                          "operator" =>  "==",
                                          "value" =>  "357, 358, 407",
                                          "is_value_processed" =>false,
                                        )
                                     )
                )
         )

  )
);
```

i want to check condition like this from array

```
if ($total_ amount >= 50 && $total_ amount <= 100)
{
.......
}
elseif ($total_ amount >= 101 && $total_ amount <= 200)
{
......
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far. And where do you want to checkj this. Did you look for any observer events you might be able to hook? At this point your question is a bit too broad and unclear to give a good answer

Comment: @Sander please loot at this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64701/i-want-to-show-next-best-volume-discount-to-customer-for-total-amount

i want to